# Recalling a password leak warning

Tags: security, password, notifications

A while back, we got a warning that our password on a particular site has appeared in a leak DB.  Where (if anywhere) in MacOS can we retrieve that notification?  Wasn't able to deal with it at the time it appeared and now I don't remember which site.

Answer (score 2):

There are several sites that will compare to leaked address/password lists - https://haveibeenpwned.com is the one I know best.

Also, Safari has an option that will show other warnings.

Prefs > Passwords > [enter admin password]

Any entry with a warning will show in Details, bottom right, what the warning is. I don't have any with a 'leaked' warning. I did a huge tidy-up of this list when it first became available & accept my remaining warnings as "don't care".
 <sub>For obvious reasons a lot of this is blurred</sub>

[image]

Comment: Not really interested in typing a hundred passwords into someone else's server, unless I change ALL of them afterward.  (Tough enough even trusting Apple with Keychain.) I will take a look at the Safari thing.

Comment: `haveibeenpawned.com` is a reputable site, and it does **email address** lookups against lists of compromised passwords.

Comment: @WGroleau - that rather tells me you didn't even bother to look.

Comment: Many of my accounts don’t have e-mail accounts associated and many have one-off addresses.